# Error CS1513 } expected. Compiler being over picky?

Tags: asp.net, razor

This is my code. It's just a basic cshtml page (not MVC) that I'm editing in a text editor. Visual Studio doesn't help much, it seems to suffer from the same issues as the compiler.

The code is printing a list of steps in a "plan" into a table, retrieved from a db query. There may be multiple plans, and each time there's a new one I want to display its name in a panel followed by its steps in a table. This means closing the current table and starting a new one.

The compiler doesn't seem to be able to handle the closing tags when they're "out of place". I've tried with and without `Html.Raw()` and the results are similar. Is there a technique that will work and allow this to compile?

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("CADDatabase");
    var count=0;
    var num="0";
    var image="blank";
    var APName="blank";
    // Attached action plan for incident
    var APIncidentQuery=@"select action_plan_name, action_plan_item_types.item_type_eng, pre_mobilisation_flag, instruction_text, isnull(action_plan_active.instruction_information,' ') as instruction_information, item_status_eng
    from action_plan, action_plan_active, action_plan_item_types, action_plan_status
    where action_plan_item_types.item_type=action_plan_active.item_type 
    and action_plan_active.item_status=action_plan_status.item_status 
    and action_plan.action_plan_id=action_plan_active.action_plan_id
    and action_plan_active.eid=(select min(eid) from agency_event where num_1=@0) order by action_plan_active.action_plan_id, active_item_id";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   <title>Process Action Plan</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <!-- Panel header with search box -->
    <div class="container-fluid ">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                        <form method="get" class="col-xs-3">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Event id" name="EventId" size="12">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Header row -->
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            @foreach(var row in db.Query(APIncidentQuery,Request.QueryString["EventId"])){
                image="Images/ActionPlans/" + @row.item_type_eng + ".png";
                // New plan
                if (row.action_plan_name != APName) {
                    // Close off previous table if there is one
                    if (APName != "blank") {
                        Html.Raw("</tbody></table></div></div>");
                    } 
                    <!-- Start new table -->
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-warning">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="plan-header">
                                    <img src="http://swi-hsiv-ps03/UKApps/Images/checklist-warning.png" height="32">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">Action plan items (@row.action_plan_name)</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Table of results -->
                            <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
                               <thead>
                                   <tr>
                                       <th>#</th>
                                       <th>Type</th>
                                       <th>Pre-dispatch</th>
                                       <th>Instruction</th>
                                       <th>Additional Info</th>
                                   </tr>
                               </thead>
                               <tbody>
                    <!-- store plan name for next iteration -->
                    @{
                        APName=row.action_plan_name;
                    }
                <!-- Populate new table -->
                } 
                <!-- List Action Plan items -->
                <tr>
                    <td>@row.item_number</td>
                    <td><img src="@image" height="30" title="@row.item_type_eng"></td>
                    @if (row.pre_mobilisation_flag == "Y") {
                        <td><img src="images/ActionPlans/done-red.png" title="Y" height="30"></td>
                    } else {
                        <td><img src="images/ActionPlans/delete-grey.png" title="N" height="30"></td>
                    }
                    <td>@row.instruction_text</td>
                    @if (row.instruction_information.Length > 4 && row.instruction_information.Substring(0,5) == "http:") {
                        <td><a href=@row.instruction_information>Additional information</a></td>
                    } else {
                        <td>@row.instruction_information</td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        @{
            Html.Raw("</tbody></table></div></div>");
        }
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Follow the tips found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406915/asp-net-how-to-resolve-cs1513-expected-error-on-page)

Comment: I believe that there is no way around it. Since a `<table>` tag opens in the `foreach` loop, it is expected to find the `</table>` tag inside the loop. You'll need to adjust your markup, which I believe will lead to a cleaner markup as well.

Comment: @vfle yes, thanks I had looked at that thread.

Comment: @TasosK. That's a bit like saying "you'll need to write it a different way". But actually, that's what I've done - rewritten it as 2 queries with a foreach loop for each one. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's the multine query. Try putting it all in a single line to see if that's the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by rewriting as 2 queries, one to get the list of plans, the other to list the items within each. Then the tables are fully contained within the foreach loops.